# Google Sheets adding weird number in 11th decimal place

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, google-sheets-timestamp, google-sheets-dates

Can anyone explain this?
I have 18 hardcoded numbers - that is, typed in, not as a result of a formula. [B1 thru B18]
I have a cell [D1] that sums those 18 numbers.
I have eleven other hardcoded numbers [cells D3 thru D13]
11 cells subtract D1 from each of D3 thru D13 [cells F3 thru F13].
Somehow, Sheets is adding weird numbers in the 11th decimal place for no particular reason.

[image: screen shot from google sheets]

In the example, all numbers are extended out to 30 decimal places just to prove there isn't a rounding error.
Again, all numbers in column B are hard coded.
If the difference is more than 10,000, then no weird decimals are added.
I assume it is related to floating point numbers, but this just feels wrong.
I retyped everything in a fresh sheet to confirm it happens consistently.

I will include the list of numbers in a comment to see if that helps anyone.

Comment: Here are the numbers in column B 6510
7984.2
89
142
3719.4
89
252
2244
89
2755.02
9097
455.04
89
89
89
8633.56
194.94
194.3

Answer (score 1):

First of all, extending numbers to 30 decimals prooves nothing (not even rounding errors).

Secondly, Google Sheets is not able to handle more than **15** decimals (eg. everything after that is irrelevant)

Thirdly, all numbers in Google Sheets acts also as placeholders for dates - for example:

```
1      = 31/12/1899
100    = 09/04/1900
-1000  = 04/04/1897
43555  = 31/03/2019
100000 = 14/10/2173
```

Also, there is a certain (+/- 10000) threshold around today's date which reflects in such manner that Google Sheets predicts it's a date, not a number. So to answer your question: those weird numbers around 11th decimal are caused because Google Sheets converts those numbers to dates eg. you summing date values instead of numbers.

[image: 0]

Therefore, to correct it, you will need to force numbers over date values which will give you:

[image: 0]